# Backing up multi-node crate cluster

Tags: backup, crate

I have seen docs on how to import data but how do I do backups?

Is there tooling, is there an API, or is it safe to copy the files on the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exporting data is done via [COPY TO](https://crate.io/docs/stable/sql/dml.html#exporting-data). Exports can go to the local filesystem or amazon s3.

every node containing data will export in parallel. you can export to a network attached storage or s3 or simply copy the exported files to another host using scp.